# How to forward blocked ports by ISP

Tags: port, blocking, isp

So I've been trying to setup a TeamSpeak 3 server on my pc but ports (9987,10011,30033) are blocked by my ISP, I've contacted them to unblock them but they didn't accept, and it's the fastest ISP in my city (as living in a 3rd world country) so it's not a good idea to connect to another ISP.

The thing is, I've tried Your-Freedom to connect to tunnel my connection & SocksCap.

The problem is, when TS works with SocksCap it doesn't show a WAN-IP that friends will use to connect to my server It says "Needs to be Requested" and when I press the Request button, I get nothing.

So, any idea what's wrong if someone has done this before? or if you have any other suggestion to run a TS server, would be very glad to hear it and really appreciate that.

P.S. as I've mentioned before, living in a 3rd world country, makes me unable to buy a VPS even the cheapest one cause there's no Visa, Credit, or paypal. so that won't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to change the default port that TeamSpeak uses?

Comment: @joejoe31b I tried everything possible, as far as I know, there's no way to change the ports.

Comment: have you tried running a local proxy with NAPT?

Answer (score 1):

download YaTQA server admin software from teamspeak sites download area, use that admin software to log onto your server from local side, once connected you select the virtual server you want to admin and you change the port the virtual server is hosted on. You also can change the file sharing port also! The port you select must be one that is not blocked by isp.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if your ISP is blocking inbound traffic on a necessary port, then there isn't a whole lot you can do. You basically have four options that I can see:

- Switch to an ISP with a less restrictive inbound traffic policy (or establish a tunnel through one and route the traffic through that tunnel)
- Run the server software somewhere else (basically a variant of "switch ISP")
- Convince the ISP to allow the traffic through (basically a variant of "less restrictive inbound traffic policy")
- Run the traffic on another, non-blocked port (work around the problem)

Let's look at these in turn:

- You say switching to a different ISP is not an option.
- You say running the server software somewhere else (on a VPS) is not an option.
- You say the ISP does not want to allow the traffic through.
- **Your only remaining option** then is to run the traffic on some other port. Some software and protocols allow that, some don't. I don't know if TeamSpeak 3 allows this or not.

If that is not an option either, then unfortunately I think you might be out of luck. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to work on that & see if it's possible, tho as far as I know TS3 ports can't be changed.